In an isosceles triangle with base $a$ and congruent side $b$ the vertex angle is equal to $20°$. Prove that $a^3 + b^3 = 3ab^2$.
I was trying to solve this problem:

In an isosceles triangle with base $a$ and congruent side $b$
the vertex angle is equal to $20°$. Prove that $a^3 + b^3 = 3ab^2$.

After a long time of thinking and trying to solve complicated trigonometric equations I was not able to solve this.
I made a lot of complex trig equations like $c^3-3\sqrt{3} c^2s+ 9cs^2-9\sqrt{3} s^3- 3(c-\sqrt{3}s)$ which I wanted to prove equals $0$ where $c:= \cos(20), \ s:=\sin(20)$
I also tried to use the identity of $\sin(3x) , \ \cos(3x)$ as the $\sin(60) , \cos(60)$ are easy to deal with.
I also tried to do some geometric construction but I failed to because I have no idea what the segment with length $3ab^2, a^3, b^3$ should be.

Can't you simply say that $\frac{a}{2} = b \cdot \cos(20°)$?

A similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4291824/947379

The idea of using the identity of $\sin(3x)$ is correct.
First, bisect the $20^\circ$ angle. As the triangle is isosceles, this is a perpendicular bisector of the base.
We will have $$\sin(3\cdot 10^\circ)=3\sin(10^\circ)-4\sin^3(10^\circ)=3\dfrac{a/2}{b}-4\dfrac{a^3/8}{b^3}=\dfrac{3a}{2b}-\dfrac{a^3}{2b^3}$$
Using that $\sin(30^\circ)=\dfrac{1}{2}$ we get $$\dfrac{3a}{b}-\dfrac{a^3}{b^3}=1\iff \dfrac{3ab^2-a^3}{b^3}=1\iff a^3+b^3=3ab^2$$
